# Linq Join variable scoping issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, linq, join

Really odd issue that I cant work out.

I am trying to join two tables in a linq statement to only retrieve records where the record in table 1 has no related rows in table 2.

I have used Joins before but for some reason I cant get VS to recognise the second table in the linq statement.

EG.

```
var result = 
(from pc in _dataSource.Payments
join bc in _dataSource.BouncedCheques

on pc.PaymentID != bc.PaymentID //This is where the error occurs, VS does not recognise "bc"

where pc.CustomerNumber == getAccountNumber
& pc.IsDeleted == false
orderby pc.PaymentDate descending
select new PaymentAllocation
{
     PaymentId = pc.PaymentID,
     PaymentDate = pc.PaymentDate,
     CustomerNumber = pc.CustomerNumber,
     ChequeReference = pc.ChequeReference,
     PaymentValue = pc.PaymentValue,
     AllocatedValue = pc.AllocatedValue,
     UnallocatedValue = pc.PaymentValue - pc.AllocatedValue,
     ReceivedBy = pc.ReceivedBy,
     PaymentType = pc.PaymentType,
     PostedDate = pc.PostedDate
});
```

Basically the problem is that the variable "bc" does not seem to be recognised, however I have several other similar Linq queries that all work well

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the syntax for join uses the keyword `equals` and not standard boolean operators.

Try replacing your join by a cartesian product of your tables:

```
from pc in _dataSource.Payments
from bc in _dataSource.BouncedCheques
where
pc.PaymentID != bc.PaymentID
&& pc.CustomerNumber == getAccountNumber
& pc.IsDeleted == false
```

Comment: So does that mean that unless I am doing a standard equals (or override equals) I have to do it this way? this seems a very inefficient way of doing different joins.

Comment: I think the idea is that a join where you don't use the equals operator has nothing more to offer performance-wise than a cartesian product with a filter.

Answer (score 0):

In the join clause you should use the equals keyword:

try:

```
on pc.PaymentID equals bc.PaymentID
```